# PostgreSQL insert triggers and many-to-many tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables in a postgres database `articles` and `users`. These two tables are connected through a many-to-many relation, so there's a third table called `articles_users` that contains foreign key relations to both `articles` and `users`.

What I'd like to do, is create a trigger that runs when a new entry is inserted into the `articles` table and connects that article to each user in my database through the `articles_users` table. Is this possible with triggers and if so, how should I write it?

I have a rough understanding of how triggers work and have some pseudosql that looks like this:

```
create function public.connect_articles_to_users() 
returns trigger as $$
begin
-- Here's some pseudocode to describe what I'd like to happen
-- Not sure if temprow is the right structure here
  for temprow in
    select * from users
      loop
        insert into articles_users (id, users.id) values (new.id, users.id)
      end loop
  return new
end;
$$ language plpgsql security definer;

-- trigger the function every time a and article is created
create trigger on_article_created
  after insert on articles
  for each row execute procedure public.connect_articles_to_users();
```

Comment: Your issue raises 2 obvious questions: 1. What happens when users are added, do they also get relationship to all articles? 2. If all articles are related to all users, what is the point of the intersection table articles_users)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your trigger is already executes the function for each row of inserted article and you don't need a loop for users, you can insert many rows in one `insert`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION connect_articles_to_users()
 RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO articles_users (article_id, user_id)
  SELECT NEW.id, id FROM users
 ;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: Here there is an example https://newbedev.com/sql-postgresql-insert-into-select-from-another-table-code-example

Comment: Yaasss! This works. Thank you so much. This saves me from a lot of pain.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the `articles_users`  table has columns `article_id` and `user_id` insert a row for every user

```
    insert into articles_users (article_id, user_id) 
    select new.id, users.id
    from users;
```